# Webpack dev server and react. Only get directory listing when running app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run the project through webpack-dev-server, all I see in the browser is the directory listing. I can navigate to the files and see them, but the app isn't actually running.

When I run just webpack, the output file is in the right format, so I don't think that is the issue. I really can't work out what the problem could be.

(The webpack-dev-server and webpack commands are run through adding to scripts in package.json. You can see it in the package.json file below).

[image: What I get in the browser]

I've broken the project down into it's simplest form. It looks like this:

[image: project file structure]

**app.js**

```
console.log("Hello");
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --hot -inline"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
  },
  module: {
  rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react'],         
        },
      ],
    },
  mode: "development"
}
```

And here is my output in terminal when I run the command

```
npm run webpack-dev-server

> my-app@0.1.0 webpack-dev-server /home/chasmani/Documents/react/project
> webpack-dev-server --hot -inline

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 5a0c6d1388d655e14809
Version: webpack 4.8.2
Time: 1100ms
Built at: 2018-05-11 17:19:57
 Asset     Size      Chunks             Chunk Names
app.js  367 KiB  javascript  [emitted]  javascript
Entrypoint main = app.js
[../node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] ../node_modules/webpack/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {javascript} [built]
[0] multi ../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./app.js 52 bytes {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js] 176 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] ../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.75 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] 3.58 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] 1.05 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] 1.66 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] 77 bytes {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] 1.31 KiB {javascript} [built]
[../node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js] 1.03 KiB {javascript} [built]
[./app.js] 36 bytes {javascript} [built]
    + 13 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

All I get is the file system. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: looks like you also want https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

Comment: Thanks Hamms - could you explain some more?

Comment: webpack dev server is doing everything it's supposed to do; exposing the files in your project through a web interface. If you want the files to be _executed_, you need to include them as javascript sources in an html file. You can do that manually, or with html-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Hamms, who left a comment but not an answer.

The reason you get the directory listing is because webpack-dev-server needs the js files to be called from an index.html file.

[html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) is one approach to generating this index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem shown above and then realized that my problem was that I was running the serve command "serve -s" from OUTSIDE the build folder. That is wrong. The correct way is to go into the build folder and then run "serve -s" from there.